# Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 with version (= 5.0.11)' when 5.0.11 runtime is present

Tags: c#, .net-5, asp.net5

I'm getting `Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 with version (= 5.0.11)` when 5.0.11 runtime is present.

This is a .Net 5 ASP.Net Core Web API and happens during publishing a the app

`dotnet publish "<csprojpath>" --configuration "Release" --output "<oPath>" --runtime "win-x64" --self-contained true`

**SDKS**

```
C:\>dotnet --list-sdks
2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

**Runtimes**

```
C:\>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

**Logs**

```
[15:14:58]  Step 8/11: [optional] :: dotnet publish (PowerShell) (4s)
[15:14:58]  [Step 8/11] PowerShell Executable: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
[15:14:58]  [Step 8/11] Working directory: D:\data\BuildAgent\work\c987603e01a118bc
[15:14:58]  [Step 8/11] Command: C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
[15:14:58]  [Step 8/11] PowerShell arguments: -NoProfile, -NonInteractive, -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, D:\data\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell462741448445389494.ps1
[15:15:00]  [Step 8/11] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.1+3e40a09f8 for .NET
[15:15:00]  [Step 8/11] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[15:15:00]  [Step 8/11] 
[15:15:00]  [Step 8/11]   Determining projects to restore...
[15:15:01]  [Step 8/11] D:\data\BuildAgent\work\c987603e01a118bc\src\D.C\D.C.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 with version (= 5.0.11) [D:\data\BuildAgent\work\c987603e01a118bc\src\D.S\D.S.csproj]
```

Comment: You need the SDK, not the runtime to publish. Edit: that's SDK 5.0.402, nevermind. What's your PATH environment variable? Is x86 prior to x64?

Comment: @CodeCaster  I don't have global.json then why does this specially wants 5.0.11?

Comment: @CodeCaster dotnet publish "<csprojpath>"
 --configuration "Release" --output "<oPath>" --runtime "win-86" --self-contained true

Comment: What is "win-86", I wonder...

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry Typo.

dotnet publish "<csprojpath>" --configuration "Release" --output "<oPath>" --runtime "win-x64" --self-contained true

Comment: Again, check your PATH. If you installed a x86 SDK or runtime before x64, the order in your PATH environment variable messes these things up.